# "Улыбнись(,) страна!" Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

В одной из телевизионных работ был использован этот конечный слоган (без запятой).
Верно ли это было: УЛЫБНИСЬ СТРАНА!
(Может ли контекст или видео влиять на наличие или отсутствие запятой?) https://youtu.be/0NAhkEx5zp8

Comment: @VeraCherss Вы по ошибке дали ответ в тексте вопроса. Чтобы дать ответ, используйте поле "Ваш ответ

Comment: А вот еще: конкурс "УЛЫБНИСЬ РОССИЯ" (http://stranadetstva30.ru/main/205). Похоже, улыбки без правил входят в моду. :))

Answer (score 6):

Запятая нужна обязательно. Явное обращение, хоть и риторическое. Понятно, что в устойчивых выражениях типа "не дай Бог", "не приведи Господь" запятая не ставится, но в нашем случае обычный случай постановки знака перед обращением.

Comment: Это "явное" обращение  даже не читается с ударением на первом слове и паузой после него, а  если всё-таки прочтешь, то в добром пожелании слышится какой-то угрожающе-приказной тон: а ну улыбнись, страна!

Answer (score 0):

Этот слоган весьма известный, уже "ушел в народ",  например:

**Улыбнись страна, юмористические миниатюры. Улыбнись Страна ТВ. Улыбнись страна** (тема на форуме). И т. д. И "обязательную" запятую никто почему-то не ставит.

**Улыбнись страна** здесь имеет значение пожелания: **пусть улыбнется страна.**

Обе формы  (*улыбнись* и *пусть улыбнется*) относятся к повелительному наклонению, но первая форма в стандартной конструкции предполагает наличие обращения.

Слоган может использовать **отклонение от стандартной формы**, чем и привлекает к себе дополнительное внимание.

"Кроме того, девиз фирмы должен быть **легкопроизносимым** – не стоит загромождать его длинными фразами и трудными для восприятия словами. В идеале слоган состоит из 2-4 слов.  Это удобно не столько для привлечения внимания, сколько для восприятия и запоминания".
[Слоган для рекламы: самые лучшие и неудачные примеры. Как придумать удачный рекламный слоган?](http://fb.ru/article/145641/slogan-dlya-reklamyi-samyie-luchshie-i-neudachnyie-primeryi-kak-pridumat-udachnyiy-reklamnyiy-slogan)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вполне возможно, что авторы слогана имели в виду простое обращение. **Новизна же формы в том,** что здесь отсутствует пауза и, соответственно, запятая. И не только пауза! Не надо забывать о том, что наличие паузы предполагает деление фразы  **на две части с ударением на каждом слове**.

Этот текст с трудом  читается так: **улыбнИсь, (пауза) странА,** но  этот же текст легко читается одной фразой: **улыбнись странА.**

**Это основной принцип слогана ― текст должен произноситься легко,** тогда он быстро запоминается и "уходит в народ".

Comment: @ Sibylla,а есть какие-нибудь правила, допускающие отсутствия запятой в слоганах? Грамота.ру считает иначе.

Comment: Вопрос № 274055   
  

    Пунктуация в рекламных слоганах.
    Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли русском языке, чётко сформулированные, правила использования пунктуации в слоганах? Не для конкретно взятого какого-то девиза, а общепринятые и прописные правила.

    И будет ли верным написание слогана?
    СВВ крепче чем металл. 

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

    ***Для слоганов действуют те же правила пунктуации, что и для обычных предложений***. Корректно: СВВ крепче, чем металл.

Comment: Серж, вряд ли есть специальные правила для слоганов, это творчество свободное, ищущее новые формы, пусть и ненормированные. К тому же формы наклонений часто используют не по правилам (например: он нашалил, а я держи ответ). Что касается этого слогана, то паузы там нет, поэтому нет и запятой. Для заголовка звучит неплохо (с ударением на втором слове).

Comment: Sibylla, пауза не всегда свидетельствует о запятой и, наоборот, там, где нет паузы, может стоять запятая.

Comment: Справедливое замечание, но вот обращение паузой выделяется всегда.  Поэтому нет паузы - нет обращения. И ударения на первом слове тоже нет (это важно).

Comment: Да, конечно, обращение всегда выделяется запятой и, следовательно, не зависит от наличия и отсутствия паузы.

Comment: @ Sibylla,  в прошлый раз, когда вы отвечали на подобный вопрос (Стоп(,) самострой!), мне ваш ответ показался интересным. Я был с ним согласен, но потом задал вопрос Грамме,ру. Они мне ответили подробно. Тогда стало ясно, что запятая в подобных случаях регулируется правилами.

Comment: Серж, а вы во всём доверяете Грамме.ру? Ведь они тоже только толкователи имеющихся правил, а не составители их.

Comment: Согласен с Сержем. По правилу обращение всегда выделяется запятой, а паузы может и не быть. Звучит так: "Васяпривет!" - "ЗдоровоЛехаКакЖенаКакСам!"

Comment: Sibylla, конечно, они только толкователи правил. Но они еще и кандидаты наук, научные сотрудники. Если в слоганах можно было отступать от правил, как вы думаете, они об этом не знали бы?

Comment: Sibylla, не думаю, что из-за одной запятой людям будет тяжело читать слоган и он не запомнится.

Comment: Серж, разумеется, это отступление от правил и ненормированная форма записи.  Просто слоган - это новая форма письма, а стандартные правила это не учитывают.  (Запятые вообще плохо смотрятся в коротких фразах,  чаще применяется тире). И фонетика конкретной фразы важна: наш вариант точно не читается с запятой. И графика тоже важна:  она необычна, она говорит о том, что это не стандартное обращение, а что-то вроде  "письменной идиомы" - лозунг, девиз, название темы.